# How to concatenate numpy arrays into a specific shape?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, mnist

I need to assign an array of `mnist` image values to the following variable...

```
x = tf.get_variable("input_image", shape=[10,784], dtype=tf.float32)
```

The problem is I need to sift the through the `mnist` data set and extract 10 images of the number 2 and assign it to `x`.

This is my approach at sifting through the data set and extracting the number 2...

```
while mnist.test.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size):
    sample_image, sample_label = mnist.test.next_batch(10)
    # get number 2
    itemindex = np.where(sample_label == 1)

    if itemindex[1][0] == 1:
        # append image to numpy
        np.append(labels_of_2, sample_image)
    # if the numpy array has 10 images then we stop
    if labels_of_2.size == 10:
        break

# assign to variable
sess.run(tf.assign(x, labels_of_2))
```

The problem is I believe my logic is flawed. I need an array with shape `[10, 784]` to satisfy the variable `x` and clearly the following line is not the way to do it...

```
np.append(labels_of_2, sample_image)
```

There must be an easy way to accomplish what I want but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget `np.append`; collect the images in a list

```
alist = []
while mnist.test.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size):
    sample_image, sample_label = mnist.test.next_batch(10)
    # get number 2
    itemindex = np.where(sample_label == 1)

    if itemindex[1][0] == 1:
        alist.append(sample_image)
    # if the list has 10 images then we stop
    if len(alist) == 10:
        break

    labels_of_2 = np.array(alist)
```

Assuming the arrays in `alist` all have the same size, e.g. (784,), then the `array` function will produce a new array with shape (10, 784).  If the images are (1,784) you could use `np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)` instead.

List append is faster and easier to use.